# Acer nitro 5 crashes frequently on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, crash, amd-ryzen

I use an Acer nitro 5 (amd chip) using Ubuntu 22.04 lts. Often the screen hangs, I can't use anything other than using the power button to shutdown and restart. I think the problem may be due to my NVIDIA driver problem.
My GPU: GTX 1650 4GB NVIDIA
This is the driver that i installed for my computer.
I'm looking forward to help because crashes are very common and cause a lot of problems for me. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and add which GPU your laptop has.

Comment: I've update GPU in my qs

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Also, are the fans working?

Comment: ram 16GB, fans is working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so I downgraded Nvidia drivers to version 525 and it works! Don't forget to uninstall the installed drivers before.